# What does pinche mi panocha mean in Spanish translation to English

Tags: traducción

I'm just trying to figure out does it mean fucking pussy or something like that? LoL I know mi is my so not right  if you drop the mi then yes but with mi means something completely different I would appreciate some help with this.

Comment: Where did you find that?

Comment: @Crazy momma The phrase *"*pinche mi panocha*" on its own is agrammatical. For example, it were "*Mi pinche panocha*" is would mean "My damn pussy". If you can, please give us the rest of the sentence and some context so that we can answer you.

Answer (score 1):

Diccionario de americanismos

panocha.
I.  1.  f. Mx, CR, Cu, PR, Co, Ec; Ho, ES, vulg; m. CR. **Vulva**. tabú; pop + cult → espon. So, pussy, sort of, yes.

pinchar(se).
I.  1.  intr. Ch, Py, Ar. **Tener una relación amorosa o sexual superficial con alguien.** pop. So, screw, sort of, yes.

But the terms seem to be found in different countries.

[ASALE.ORG](https://www.asale.org/damer/pinchar)

Asociación de Academias de la Lengua Española

I guess one could come to the conclusion that it means what the OP says it means, which I just cannot bring myself to type here. It's just too vulgar for me.

Answer (score -1):

**"Pinche mi Panocha"**

Literalmente significaría, "Pinche (usted) mi Vagina"

---

Según la RAE

**Pinche**.

1. com. Persona que presta servicios auxiliares en la cocina.
2. adj. C. Rica, El Salv. y Nic. tacaño (‖ **miserable**).
3. adj. despect. malson. Méx. ruin (‖ **despreciable**).

En el estudio que realiza Marco Antonio Pérez Durán y Oscar Arriaga Olguín

"**Inventario fraseológico de las groserías en estudiantes de San Luis Potosí**"

la palabra "**pinche**" referida a una persona o cosa tiene entre otros, el significado de desgraciado/a, ojete/a (tonto, estúpido), culera (en México miedoso/a o cobarde, en el Salvador hombre homosexual), maldito/a, etcétera.

Otros ejemplos que aparecen en el trabajo acompañando a la palabra "**pinche**";

- pinche bato
- pinche cabeza de mojón
- pinche joto
- pinche madre
- pinche pendejo
- pinche perra
- pinche perro
- pinche prostituta

Si atendemos al verbo "**pinchar"** 1. tr. Clavar algo punzante en alguien o algo.

"Pinche" se trata del "Imperativo del verbo pinchar", "**pinche (usted)**"

**Panocha**

(Del lat. vulg. panucŭla, mazorca, y este del lat. panicŭla, dim. de panus, mazorca de hilo).

1. f. panoja.
2. f. C. Rica. empanada (‖ masa de pan rellena).
3. f. coloq. Cuba y El Salv. **vulva**.
4. f. coloq. Cuba. **vagina**.

Igualmente en la Academia Mexicana de la Lengua, la palabra "**Panocha**" significa "**vagina**", "**vulva**".

De esta manera, atendiendo tanto al verbo **"pinchar"**, como a los vulgarismos "**pinche**" en donde se observan las distintas construcciones con la palabra "pinche" y en la que no existe en ningún modo una voz o locuciones intermedias de este tipo. Si a eso sumamos la otra voz "**panocha**", vemos que el "**mi**" posesivo es el que hace de enlace entre "pinche" y "panocha", "pinche **mi** panocha", por lo que la voz "pinche" se referiría al verbo "pinchar", "pinche (usted)" y no adjetivo "pinche".

Así "**pinche (usted) mi panocha**", vendría a significar entre otros, "pinche (usted) mi vagina", "aguijone (usted) mi vagina", "atraviese (usted) mi vagina"...